# How make the HTML I took from another site show up properly?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, microsoft-edge, inspect-element

I used inspect-element to change words and images on a website for a project and then saved the newly edited site as a file, but after working fine the first few times I ran it. The file started to show up weird. It originally looked like the linked Clickhole.com article that I've linked albeit with my modifications. And now shows up broken. So I was wondering how to make the file look right again.

It might be because the file was originally ran in on a Google-chrome laptop but doesn't know what to do trying to run on a Mac or Windows computer but I'm not sure.

[How the edited code shows up](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=c62a1f7a51&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-a:r2421490639731016661&th=17f98c025b7a66bb&view=att&disp=inline&realattid=f_l0v7oo7x0&ser=1&saddbat=ANGjdJ9EIpHo26SLC_b1gtZjjLkCGjsv_dZao9QvPzlSKVJBxBQ2rqvc9IVTQvAAd_gwSKkYJl8sTLJRKrJSetbY2GeWDWSayHvfhUVpOI6rpa_lyWQ1J9-y6wMv4BxFSmpDsgTEmOwc_VYiaNtVZkkSzIaxVbHuKiije277jM_YjV_2btA5CZ9KxkJY-dd5QHSb0jwpUwmjFAoFrWjtWVPBDzhmpQsw8_f58ipS4RK46jE7oAidRhP9dWxTnbOAFWUBjKozfW_rM7Grq-vT2wYQdqYem8LOIidRRW7dHWyxafCFD10SGhH9O3_4hHRmtGBteQ3tVR2a1n0vBAZ94aM9VomHXFNUUR4bH3R_cNjEN6dMEAIthVZRs1uLWd9fnZiAHX0F9_wDs0qVRm5ir5j_nistZIUp-LXTvAXiJHUXW-kxnJ4dKKDnMMA-zxiWO1WzWr11DzrCPGd6mSRap0soItVA7iNqqLCFafVFNmN_Esu0REp2QEk_I3dwToICK7gQ6Uu9FbOqUOXrw_RhWeQgbgxS2sMVs0a1q6a94Pudk80tMlHDCpXZGdmWI3ZdZr2DpVDIWBqCCqwhnaoc1AEsBDO-nwW59BWt0-gZXqjctmHizsn4f3jDNHTh4ZYspEuNAmazV22mj5N0FJdyxfS_VOs-7lfDoNJNtwrcGXTuIp0Qc4VqmAvr8bJhZtY)
[How it originally looked](https://clickhole.com/overstepping-her-bounds-j-k-rowling-has-announced-tha-1828826710/)

Comment: Most websites uses a specific CSS file. Without the CSS, the website will look ugly

Answer (score 1):

You would need to download all the assets the HTML file is pointing to, like the images and style.css. Or you could add a [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag in the head element of the HTML file to make the website look for assets in the original.

```
<base href="https://clickhole.com/overstepping-her-bounds-j-k-rowling-has-announced-tha-1828826710/">
```